# how to get private keys from certificates into the p12 file?

Tags: python, cryptography, digital-signature, pkcs#12

Inside a .p12 file, I have 2 certificates of which one of them is expired. With the cryptography library, I can obtain the certificate but I don't know how to obtain the private key of that certificate, since the library only obtains a private key (private_key) from the load_key_and_certificates method.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import pkcs12

p12_file_path = 'my_file.p12'
password = 'mypassword'.encode()

with open(p12_file_path, 'rb') as p12_file:
    private_key, certificate, additional_certs = pkcs12.load_key_and_certificates(p12_file.read(), password, default_backend())

# additional certificates are in the additional_certs
third_certificate = additional_certs[1] # this is my certificate
print(third_certificate)
```

As seen in the code, the expired certificate is found in the certificate variable, and the valid certificate is found in additional_certs[1].

Is there a way to obtain/generate the private key or delete this certificate within the .p12 file?

Comment: Of course, with KeyStore Explorer I can detect that there are 2 certificates, in my case, I want to automate this process to sign PDF documents, but I cannot use the other certificate to sign the PDF since I cannot obtain the key of that certificate.

Comment: Sure, but my goal is to do it at the python level, unless there is a keystore package for python.